# Android Websocket in service

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous, websocket

I need to build a Websocket in my app that is always listening for incoming message. (I want to control the app via Websocket)

when ever there is a new message, check what is it and execute task. 
example: if websocket receive `<play>`, then play the video, `<pause>`, `<stop>`...

So far I have successfully build the socket using `[koush/AndroidAsync][1]` library in my main activity.
but when I play the video I Go onto the VideoActivity so I lose the connection,

Here is the code I have so far in my main activity. My question really is : How can I have this method always running in the background.

```
private void connectToPASocket()
    {
        makeLog("i", "connectToPASocket()");

        //Checking
        if(socket!=null && socket.isOpen())


            return;

        //Initiate web socket connection
        AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket(SOCKET_ADDR, null, new AsyncHttpClient.WebSocketConnectCallback()
        {   @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket)
            {   makeLog("w", "connectToPASocket() > AsyncHttpClient > onCompleted");


                if (ex != null) {
                    makeLog("w", "connectToPASocket() > AsyncHttpClient > onCompleted > if (ex!=null)");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }





                    socket = webSocket;
                    socket.setStringCallback(new StringCallback() {
                        public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                            makeLog("v", "socket.setStringCallback > onStringAvailable - s => " + s);

                            System.out.println("I got a string: " + s);
                            message = s;
                            runOnUiThread(onMessageReceive);


                        }//end onStringAvailable
                    });//end socket.setStringCallback


                    socket.setDataCallback(new DataCallback() { //Find out what this does
                        @Override
                        public void onDataAvailable(DataEmitter emitter, ByteBufferList bb) {
                            makeLog("v", "socket.setDataCallback > onDataAvailable | emitter=> " + emitter + " | bb => " + bb);

                            System.out.println("I got some bytes!");
                            // note that this data has been read
                            bb.recycle();
                        }
                    });//end webSocket.setDataCallback



            }//end onCompleted
        });//end AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance()
    }//end connectToPASocket

    Runnable onMessageReceive = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {



            if(message.equals("PlayVideo1")) { Utils.makeAlertDialog(HomeActivity.this, "WebSocket Message :", message, false);

            playVideo("one"); }

if(message.equals("stop")) { pVideo("stop");}
if(message.equals("pause")) { pVideo("pause");}
        }// end public void run()
    };// end Runnable onMessageReceive = new Runnable()
```

The method payVideo() will be in MainActivity

The method pVideo() will be in VideoActivity

Answer (score 0):

Use Service Component:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

It should work. But don't know when would be the best time for stopping Service (becouse it could work "forever").

Maybe after MainActivity is closed, send msg to Service that "it should close itself too after X minutes" (so there is a time for reconnect Activity to Service)